# Unable to stop a C program with infinite loop and printf within on macOS

Tags: c, macos, terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    while(1) {
        printf("!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my program. When I run it in the terminal, I can't stop it in any way (<kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl-\</kbd>. ...), and the terminal just blocks.
Then I have to force quit the entire terminal.
Is there a better way to stop it? (My system is macOS Monterey 12.2.1 Intel.)

Comment: It should not block. Perhaps there is just a lot of data in the stdout buffer. You can always bring up another terminal, and kill its pid. We all assume this is local rather than over a network link of some sort.

Comment: Can't reproduce on macOS Catalina: Ctrl+C stops execution as expected. Try spamming Ctrl+C until the program terminates

Comment: What if you put a tiny pause after the `printf` function? I think the program fills up some buffer so quickly, you cannot interrupt it in time... But just a guess. On old computers it was really easy to achive

Comment: Rather to my surprise, I can reproduce this on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 for Intel.  The entire terminal locks up — using plain old Mac Terminal.app.  It seems to be specific to the `!` character; when I changed the program to print `@` symbols (and a newline every 10,000 characters), I was able to break OK — no locked up terminal.  I'd put it down to a bug in Terminal.app and "don't do it".

Comment: And on a little further experimentation, it seems to be the newlines that help — removing the newlines and just continually printing `@` symbols locks up the terminal again.  It's probably something to do with storing the history of the output.  It's still a bug in Terminal.app — just a somewhat different one from what I first thought it might be.  You can report it to Apple.  It might even get fixed.  It's still simplest not to do it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the fault on my Mac (MacOS 12.3.1, 2018 6-core i7 mac Mini, Apple clang 13.0.0).  Ctrl+C always stops the program immediately for me.